# Удаление данных из DBF

Tags: dbf

Как известно при удаление данные в DBF становятся "скрытыми" - помеченными на удаление, вроде так)

Provider = VFPOLEDB

Вопросы:

- Как удалять данные сразу?
- Можно ли при удалении через простой "Delete", при последующем добавлении вместо удаленной (скрытой) записи занести новые данные (перезаписать и снять пометку удаления)?

Comment: метка c# действительно имеет прямое отношение к вопросу?

Comment: не уверен, просто вся работа с dbf будет проходить через приложение разработанное на C#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Выполнить команду `PACK`. Важно: соединение должно быть с параметром `EXCLUSVE=YES` (аналог команды FoxPro `USE <table> EXCLUSIVE`). Другие пользователи не смогут использовать открытую монопольно таблицу.
2. Можно поиграть с параметром `DELETED` (опять же, аналог `SET DELETED ON/OFF` в FoxPro). Соответственно, когда надо перезаписать данные ставим `DELETED=NO`, обновляем данные, делаем `RECALL`. Но это как-то неправильно на мой взгляд. Удалили - значит удалили.

Comment: Буду пробовать, спасибо!